# How do I make the shapes on the door of cars?

Tags: modeling

I have a question about creating the "designs" in the doors of cars. I have really never understood how to make the shapes that are on the cars. I'm working on a 2010 Zenvo ST1 and I'm puzzled on how to make this door.I can not figure out how to make the haunch of the car go into the door and then fade away while the front fender air vent goes starts to come up on the door. Any tips?

Thanks!

[image]